# Google OAuth in Java Servlet [localhost] callback

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, oauth, scribe

I created a Java Servlet Application which has Google OAuth Sign in using Scribe. The callback URL at Developers Console is `http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback`
Now, if somebody accesses my application on LAN using my Local IP, they couldn't sign in since the callback was defined as localhost. Is there any workaround [Except deploying the app on the web]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. unless the user is on your localhost, it will not work without deploying on a publically available hostname/ip address.